# TFS 2017 Build Fails - can't publish test results

Tags: visual-studio-2017

TFS 2017 Build is failing on the Visual Studio Test task when it tries to publish tests result.  Using task version 2.* ... version 1.* was not working anymore (couldn't find path vstest.console.exe and acted strange when I put specific path)... how can I get this to work?  using tfs 2017.5 on the build server, and TFS Version 15.117.26714.0, using the latest agent from that.

2017-09-21T20:29:13.5158841Z Results File: D:\agent1_work\1\s\Dev\20170305_MD_4.4\TestResults\TfsService_DEVBUILD5 2017-09-21 15_14_33.trx

2017-09-21T20:29:14.5470386Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.

2017-09-21T20:29:14.5470386Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1

2017-09-21T20:29:17.9532729Z ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: '', hexadecimal value 0x10, is an invalid character. Line 10256, position 10.

2017-09-21T20:29:17.9532729Z ##[error]Vstest exited with return code: 1.

Answer (score 0):

OK found an answer, have to use a newer version of vstest.console.exe provided by the TFS tasks team.  see last item here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/683

basically, need pass custom vstest.console.exe path which is VS-Insallation-Directory\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe in your vstest V2 task.